# Protect SSIS Packages when deployed on production servers

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

**Problem**: When SSIS packages are deployed to production SQL Server, DBAs can export the project, open it on Visual Studio and make changes to packages or worse, copy the logic inside them.

**Is it possible to encrypt the SSIS project and then deploy it on SQL server in the encrypted form ?**

I have already tried to change protection level of packages, but **while deploying it the wizard changes this protection level** [image: here]
Therefore, the end-users/dba-s can export the project and copy the logic inside the packages.

I also have read about the user-roles of SSISDB but that kind of protection won't protect the intellectual property of the packages since its up to the DBAs there to change the roles because its their database.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably no. In order to execute the package, the SSIS runtime will have to decrypt it first, and if it can do that, then DBAs also can. Your problem is that you have untrustworthy DBAs, and it can't be solved on technological level AFAIK.

Comment: @RogerWolf how about digital signing of packages ?

Comment: Digital signature ensures that the signed data isn't tampered with. When you sign something, it isn't encrypted - everybody can read its contents.